# SwipeListView unresponsive (Github example added)

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-listview, navigation-drawer, pull-to-refresh

Github link with problem example: https://github.com/ghost606/TestSwipeListView

I am using `SwipeListView` library from https://github.com/47deg/android-swipelistview. But my swipe gestures are very unresponsive.

This is what i want to have:

[image]

My problem is that the gestures are very unresponsive. Maybe it's the combination of the libraries that I am using: `ActionBarSherlock`, `Pull-To-Refresh` and `DrawerLayout`.

Can somebody help me fix this?

This is my code:

MainActivity XML:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/content_frame"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/menu_list"
    android:layout_width="240dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
    android:divider="@android:color/white"
    android:dividerHeight="2dp"
    android:padding="4dp"
    android:background="@drawable/border_top" />
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

The Fragment that implements the swipelistview and the drawerlayout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="be.appmax.ktsjjt.fragments.BeersListFragment">

<uk.co.senab.actionbarpulltorefresh.extras.actionbarsherlock.PullToRefreshLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/ptr_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <com.fortysevendeg.swipelistview.SwipeListView
        xmlns:swipe="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/lv_beers"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        swipe:swipeFrontView="@+id/front"
        swipe:swipeBackView="@+id/back"
        swipe:swipeCloseAllItemsWhenMoveList="true"
        swipe:swipeActionLeft="choice"
        swipe:swipeMode="left"
        swipe:swipeOpenOnLongPress="true"
        swipe:swipeOffsetLeft="275dp">

    </com.fortysevendeg.swipelistview.SwipeListView>
</uk.co.senab.actionbarpulltorefresh.extras.actionbarsherlock.PullToRefreshLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Fragment Code:

```
public class BeersListFragment extends Fragment implements OnRefreshListener {

private BeerAdapter beerAdapter;
private PullToRefreshLayout pullToRefreshLayout;
private SwipeListView listView;

private List<Beer> beers = new ArrayList<Beer>();

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    beers.addAll(Shared.dbRepo.beerRepository.getAll());
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_beers, container, false);
}

@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

    listView = (SwipeListView) view.findViewById(R.id.lv_beers);
    pullToRefreshLayout = (PullToRefreshLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.ptr_layout);

    beerAdapter = new BeerAdapter(getActivity(), R.layout.row_beer, beers);
    listView.setAdapter(beerAdapter);
    listView.setSwipeListViewListener(new SwipeListViewHandler());

    ActionBarPullToRefresh.from(getActivity())
            .allChildrenArePullable()
            .listener(this)
            .useViewDelegate(ListView.class, new AbsListViewDelegate())
            .setup(pullToRefreshLayout);
}

@Override
public void onRefreshStarted(View view) {
    //RELOAD EVERYTHING
}

private class SwipeListViewHandler implements SwipeListViewListener {

    @Override
    public void onOpened(int i, boolean b) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onClosed(int i, boolean b) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onListChanged() {

    }

    @Override
    public void onMove(int i, float v) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onStartOpen(int i, int i2, boolean b) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onStartClose(int i, boolean b) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onClickFrontView(int i) {
        Beer beer = beerAdapter.getItem(i);
        Tools.startFragment(getActivity(), new BeerDetailFragment(beer), getResources().getString(R.string.title_beer_detail));
    }

    @Override
    public void onClickBackView(int i) {
        Beer beer = beerAdapter.getItem(i);

        Dialogs dialogs = new Dialogs(getActivity());
        dialogs.drinkDialog(new DrinkHandler(getActivity(), beer.getId()), beer.getName());
    }

    @Override
    public void onDismiss(int[] ints) {

    }

    @Override
    public int onChangeSwipeMode(int i) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void onChoiceChanged(int i, boolean b) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onChoiceStarted() {

    }

    @Override
    public void onChoiceEnded() {

    }

    @Override
    public void onFirstListItem() {

    }

    @Override
    public void onLastListItem() {

    }
}
}
```

Comment: You set allChildrenArePullable on the PullToRefresh layout, although all the children have their own swipe listeners. That's probably why the app isn't very responsive.

Comment: It makes it a littlebit more responsive but is is not what it has to be :)